# How to make the touch zone of tabs wider in TabLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-tablayout

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.Android application, and I can't find a way to make the touch zone of my TabLayout wider. On the left you have the current touch area, on the right you have what I would like :

[image]

Don't hesitate to ask in comments if you need some more code, but this is just a basic TabLayout, which is scrollable, and set up with a ViewPager (but it should'nt have any effect). I can scroll easily, but if I want to touch the name of a category (like "Toutes", "Alimentation" or "Transport") to go to the tab, I often have to touch two or three times because the touch area is too small.

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tb_homePage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tabLayout_background"
                local:tabMode="scrollable"
                local:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                style="@style/CustomTabBar" />
```

In my Activity class, I can just access the TabLayout using this :

> FindViewById(Resource.Id.tb_homePage)

Do you guys have any idea about how to do this ? Thanks :)

**EDIT 1 : CustomTabBar style & tabLayout_background.xaml**

*CustomTabBar style*

```
  <style name="CustomTabBar" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabMinWidth">5dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15.6sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">fonts/AvenirLTStd-Roman.otf</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tablayout_text_color</item>
  </style>
```

*tabLayout_background.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:angle="90"
          android:startColor="#00000000"
          android:endColor="#0D000000"
          android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Please post your code about `CustomTabBar` style  and tabLayout_background.

Comment: Sure, I edited my post York Shen :)

Comment: Delete `tabPaddingStart` and `tabPaddingEnd` properties works fine.

Comment: The problem is that if I put a bigger padding, the space between the tabs is also bigger. Instead of seeing 3 or 4 tabs, I can only see 2 tabs on the top of the screen and this is quite ugly :/
This is why I've put a padding of 0

Comment: Why you put a bigger padding?

Comment: If I delete tabPaddingStart and tabPaddingBottom properties (that are set to 0), the padding is bigger, like if there was a default value for them
Also, it expends the touch area horizontally but not vertically, I've to put a top/bottom margin to expend the touch area vertically

Comment: So you could expend the touch area horizontally by using `tabPaddingStart` and `tabPaddingEnd`, expend the touch area vertically by using `top/bottom` margin, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to do, but if I add some padding, the space between the tabs expends too (if you see the screen captures I've put on my post, if I add padding, the blank space between "Toutes" and "Alimentation", for example, will be 2 times bigger, which is not acceptable).